# Help understanding the parkour tutorial in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d, cocos2d-x-js

I was practicing the [parkour tutorial for chapter 7](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/parkour-game-with-javascript-v3.0/chapter7/en/index.html), but I failed to understand why we should move the same delta movement of `this.gameLayer`, which contains the background layer and the animation layer in opposite direction. Why do we do this?

Answer (score 1):

**This is to keep the player centered on the screen (while maintaining the illusion of motion).**

The player is moving (right) relative to `this.gamelayer`. If `this.gamelayer` is shifted to the left the same amount, the two movements will 'cancel' each other out.

---

The paragraphs right before these instructions explained in slightly different words:

> Since the physic body will move right infinitely and the sprite will
>   synchronize it's position with the physic body.
>
> A few seconds later, the player will go outside of the screen, just as
>   it is in the last tutorial.
>
> So we need to move the game layer's x position each frame to make it
>   in a visible range.